# Unable to deactivate UISegmentedControl Button in combination with Appearance Proxy

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a strange problem. If I use the UISegmentedControl appearance proxy then I cannot disable a segmented control button anymore. The method doSmth gets triggered when I touch the left segmented control button even If I have it deactivated.

If I remove the setBackgroundImage calls, then it works as expected and the button is deactivated. Unfortunately I have to style the button.

Here is my code:

```
UIImage* segmentdEnabled = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentEnabled.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7)]; 
UIImage* segmentDisabled = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentDisabled.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentdEnabled forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentDisabled forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];  

NSArray* items =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"▲",@"▼",nil];
UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 30);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doSmth:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];  // <-- Does not work

UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem; 

[segmentedControl release];
[buttonItem release];
```

}

```
- (void)doSmth:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Click");
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you for reading this.
mark

Comment: Tested and hereby confirmed, you should file a bug at apple's bugreporter. Tell me if you don't, then i will.